# Adjust grid points to map

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to generate equidistant points on a map, I used QGis to do it, but the problem is that some points are out of the map area. I'd like to consider only the points inside the map.

This is an image with the issue described above:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the clip tool : Vector > Geoprocessing tools > Clip. First input is your point layer, second input your polygon layer.

Comment: I did this but the new generated layer is empty after I create it. Do you know what's possibly wrong?

Comment: @Rod0n - Make sure the CRS for both layers are the same.

Comment: Your layers probably have a different CRS. Check the CRS (Right click on the layer, Properties, General). If they are indeed different, reproject one of your layers into the CRS of the other one. Simplest way is 'right click > Save As' and choose the correct CRS.

Comment: Excellent!. The error appears when the option "Add result to canvas" is not selected.